# How to get user details from OpenID server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid

I'm wanting to save some OpenId fields to a localdatabase table, such as

•Full Name
•openid url
•passworg

how to get those attributes from openid server?

please send me some example code in asp.net, c#...

Comment: You may want to read up on how OpenID works: http://tinisles.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-does-openid-work.html.  There is a .net implementation here: http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/.  NOTE: you will never get an OpenId user's password, that's kind of the point.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'll be using DotNetOpenAuth, see these pages:

1. [Simple Registration](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/openid-simple-registration-extension-for-obtaining-user-attributes/)
2. [AXFetchAsSregTransform](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/the-axfetchassregtransform-behavior/)

And know that for some providers like Google, the only way to get email address is to mark it as Required when you formulate the request.